# Generate random numbers which sum must be constant by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, distribution

I am not able to solve one problem. I am trying to generate random numbers having fixed total sum and not fixed period. I tried to increase by the average value by percent until mid of period and decrease it until end of period but the total sum is changing. That is why I dont know how to generate numbers. Requirements: Total sum must be fixed. Period can be changed. The distribution of generated numbers must be increased till mid of period and decreased till to the end of period.The first generated random number must be equal to the average value (average value=total/period) My VBA code

```
Sub Distribution_and_Graph()

Dim Start As Date
Dim EndP As Date
Dim Duration As Integer
Dim NoDays As Integer
Dim manHours As Long
Dim averageManHours As Long
Dim LC As Integer
Dim i As Integer 
Dim percent1 As Integer

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Distribution").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Distribution"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set DGSheet = Worksheets("Distribution")


Worksheets("Distribution").Activate

Start = Application.InputBox("Enter your START date of project, ex 01.12.2020 ")
If Start = False Then Exit Sub
EndP = Application.InputBox("Enter you END date of project, ex 01.12.2020 ")
If EndP = False Then Exit Sub
manHours = Application.InputBox("Enter the TOTAL MAN HOURS")
If manHours = False Then Exit Sub

percent1 = Application.InputBox("Enter your starting period's PERCENTAGHE rate distribution , ex 50,65,10 ")
If percent1 = False Then Exit Sub
Duration = -Int(CDbl(Start)) + Int(CDbl(EndP)) + 30 
NoDays = EndP - Start + 1


Range("A1").Value = "Months"
Range("A3").Value = "Total man/hours"
Range("A2").Value = "QTY of workers"
Range("A4").Value = "Ðàñõîäíèêè"

Range("B1").Value = Start
Range("B1").Resize(NoDays).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, Type:=xlChronological, Date:= _
xlMonth, Step:=1, Stop:=EndP, Trend:=False



 LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Cells(3, 2).Value = (manHours * 30) / Duration

 For i = 2 To LC * 0.5
 Cells(3, i + 1).Value = Cells(3, i).Value * (1 + percent1 / 100)

  Cells(2, i).Value = Cells(3, i).Value / 330 ' Must be changed
  Cells(4, i).Value = Cells(3, i).Value * 382  'Must be changed
  Cells(2, i).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
  Cells(3, i).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
  Cells(4, i).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
   Next i

   For i = LC * 0.500000000000001 To LC
   Cells(3, i + 1).Value = Cells(3, i).Value * (1 - percent1 / 100)

   Cells(2, i).Value = Cells(3, i).Value / 330 ' Must be changed
   Cells(4, i).Value = Cells(3, i).Value * 382  'Must be changed
   Cells(2, i).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    Cells(3, i).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    Cells(4, i).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
   Next i

 End Sub
```

Comment: "The first generated random number must be equal to the average value" so it can't be random then?

Comment: @Tim Williams Thank you. I have solved